# I'm using MongoSkin in my Node.js application and after a period of inactivity it loses connectivity with the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mlab, mongoskin

I'm building [my first Node.js application](https://github.com/Chevex/CodeTunnel) and I've run into an issue with [MongoDB](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin). I'm using the MongoSkin driver.

Once I start my application it all works great. I can sit and toy with it for an hour and it will continue to work. However, if I let it sit for a few minutes without any activity then the next request will result in an error:

> Error: connection closed
>       at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (X:\Code\CodeTunnel\node_modules\mongoskin\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:520:35)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
>       at connection.on._self._poolState (X:\Code\CodeTunnel\node_modules\mongoskin\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:109:15)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
>       at Socket.closeHandler (X:\Code\CodeTunnel\node_modules\mongoskin\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:427:12)
>       at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
>       at Socket._destroy.destroyed (net.js:358:10)
>       at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)

I've tried adding `auto_reconnect=true` to the connection string as is suggested on the [mongoskin documentation](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin) but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured this one out. The solution is rather simple.

## [USE MONGOOSE](http://mongoosejs.com/)

*...or something else*.

I've had nothing but problems with MongoSkin and after finally taking the time to learn Mongoose I prefer it anyway. The model paradigm is wonderful, especially since each model has its own persistence methods for saving changes to the document. The use of promises to create a fluent query API is so powerful and sooo much easier to read than the standard callback hell provided by the native MongoDB driver. Callback hell is only slightly mitigated by MongoSkin and it's still very hard to read the more complicated queries.

Edit: Downvote.....really? What thoughts were going through your head Mr. downvote? *"Mongoose isn't my preferred ORM so here's a downvote."*?

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. hate the fact downvotes are anonymous.